# Enlarging the axes text when frame is true

Tags: plotting

I'd like to enlarge the text fonts of the axis, and the numbers on the axis have a different size. There are some similar pages, but the answers work only when the frame is NOT true. In the following code, I'd like to enlarge the text fonts to 18 and the numbers to 14. Do you have any idea? My code does not work well:

```
Plot [Sin[x], {x, 0, 7}, GridLines -> None,  PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thick}, FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 18], FrameLabel -> {Style["x", FontSlant -> Italic], "sin(x)"},  LabelStyle ->  {Bold},  BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 14}, Frame ->  True]
```

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 7}, GridLines -> None, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thick},
  FrameLabel -> {Style["x", FontSlant -> Italic], "sin(x)"}, 
 FrameTicksStyle -> {Directive[Green, 14], Directive[Orange, 14]}, 
 LabelStyle -> {Bold, Directive[Red, 18]}, Frame -> True]
```

I added colors for easier debugging...

[image]